# How to convert NSString to UIColor

Tags: xcode, string, nsstring, ios5, uicolor

I have a pickerView which has a component of colors.

I have a textField (textOther), now I have NSMutableArray of all the available colors which are explicitly defined.

How do I pass all those colors(which are strings!) to these textField?

textField setTextColor will set only a single color, but to pass string to a color how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the cleanest way to do this would be by making an `NSDictionary` with predefined `UIColor` instances, and map them as key value pairs; keys being the string that represents the color, value being the actual `UIColor` object.

So if you'd want to have both red and blue as possible colors (which are now in an `NSMutableArray` if I understood correctly), you'd make an `NSDictionary` like this:

```
NSArray * colorKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"blue" nil];
NSArray * colorValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
NSDictionary * colorMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:colorValues forKeys:colorKeys];
```

If you then want to pass a color (given a string AKA the key of said color), you can simply do this:

```
NSString * chosenColor = textField.text; // extract desired color from input in textField
textField.textColor = [colorMap valueForKey:chosenColor]; // use this color string to find the UIColor element in the colorMap
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 8):

It´s better to create a method to convert for NSString to UIColor. You shoud have a NSString with for example whiteColor or blueColor and you can convert it in the following way:

```
  -(UIColor *)getColor:(NSString*)col

  {

  SEL selColor = NSSelectorFromString(col);
  UIColor *color = nil;
  if ( [UIColor respondsToSelector:selColor] == YES) {

    color = [UIColor performSelector:selColor];
   }  
    return color;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert from NSString to UIColor:

```
NSString *redColorString = @"25";
NSString *greenColorString = @"82";
NSString *blueColorString = @"125";

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:[redColorString floatValue]/255.0
                                 green:[greenColorString floatValue]/255.0
                                  blue:[blueColorString floatValue]/255.0
                                 alpha:1.0];
```