# Convert NSString color name to UIColor

Tags: ios, uicolor

I have a task  to convert NSString color name ex:"Green" from configuration.plist file to a UIColor or a hex color code ex: "00ff00". I already have a code to convert hex color code to UIColor. I tried to use few another code sample for this task but is not working.
Please help me out with a solution for this.

Comment: you want to convert Hex color code to UIColor right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert NSString to UIColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228339/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-uicolor)

Comment: @Darshan, the user input will be like** "Lime"  **and it should apply the color accordingly.

Comment: @PrashanthKp  For done this kind of thing you have to create rule sheet and need to add each and every color with hex code or RGB code. Bcz there is no any method which is directly convert your string to UIColor.

Comment: I would not use the raw colour's name as reference, even if you could convert the raw string into a _selector_ to be called, there is no guarantee the the methods' names will not changed in future; especially if you intent using Swift – so I would store RGB or ARGB/RGBA codes instead.

Comment: Thanks @Darshan/ @holex, I'm going to create a new plist or an enum for working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using swift you can easly develop that system. All start defining a set of possibile colors in an enum like this:

```
enum MyColor: String {
    case green
    case red
    case blue
    // and so on

    var hex: Int {
        switch self {
            case green: return 0xABCDF
            case red: return 0xABCDF
            case blue: return 0xABCDF
        }

    }
}
```

Then you need a new init for the UICOlor class that use this new enum

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(myColor: MyColor) {
        self.init(hex: myColor.raw)
    }

    init(hex: Int) {
    }
}
```

After that you can initilize yor colors like this:

```
let theColor = MyColor(rawValue: "green")
let color = UIcolor(myColor: theColor)
```

Comment: Thanks iGenio, i'll try this out.

Comment: sorry if there is some syntax error, but i don't have xcode right now.

Comment: that's not an issue, but I got what you were trying to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be achieved is if you store hex color codes against color names in your app.

You can either maintain a property list or store these key value pairs in core data.

Your application would do something like this

Red:'Hex for red'
Blue:'Hex for Blue'
Green:'Hex for Green'

The manner in which you store these key value pairs is upto you. Now when you need to get a color from a color name, simply look up it's hex code and convert it into UIColor.

You would have to do this for all the colors that you expect in you application

Comment: Thanks Shayan, is there any other way of achieving my task.

Comment: @PrashanthKp not in my opinion. You can do some research on the internet to be sure

Comment: Thanks @Shayan, actually I'm searching for the solution for this for a while now, but I think this can be the solution as few people have already suggested me to do this.